# Default loaded packages in R for SQL Server R

Tags: r, sql-server

I make heavy use of running R scripts inside of SQL Server (`EXEC   sp_execute_external_script`).  However, I tend to use the same packages over and over again (i.e. dplyr) and having to load the package on each query slows the execution by a few seconds.  Is there a way to have a certain set of packages always loaded and available for use without having to load them via library()?